# Adobe tag manager - Direct Call Routes - Direct call rule "DCTEST" not found

Tags: adobe, adobe-analytics

Just wanted to know if anyone has ever seen this error when setting up Adobe Tag Manager Direct Call Routes. Direct call rule "DCTEST" not found.

I've logged created a new direct call rule named it DC TEST

In the conditions section named it DCTEST

In Adobe Analytic selected -> s.t(); - increment a pageview

Then in Javascript selected Non-Sequential and created a javascript script and added 
      window.alert("DC Fired")

Then in my localhost called 
               _satellite.track("DCTEST");

I get the error: 
              SATELLITE: Direct call Rule "DCTEST" not found

Event based tracking works and datalayer is populated as expected but when creating a direct call rule it doesn't seem to find what I've set up?

Followed the adobe video but still no luck?

https://outv.omniture.com/?v=tvaTY4ZzoJ087ioJpJptl9npM_8QGDxU

Any ideas?

Can anyone get the video to tutorial to work?

https://outv.omniture.com/?v=tvaTY4ZzoJ087ioJpJptl9npM_8QGDxU

Thanks

Comment: did you publish the direct call rule? If not, you will need to put dtm in staging mode to see your changes

Comment: Yes I put it in staging mode. But still no luck.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be much documentation on this anyone successfully set this up?

Comment: Check that you are in staging by running _satellite.settings.isStaging in the console. And just to be sure, debug mode is different than loading the staging lib

Comment: I've made lots of direct call rules. The only time I have seen that message is a) when the rule doesn't exist, or b) I haven't published yet and am not in staging mode.

Comment: I tried _satellite.settings.isStaging and it says false.. so what I thought was incorrect sorry about that. But I published the rule and now I get undefined when calling _satellite.track("DCTEST");

Comment: How do you load the staging library..? I was using a built in google web browser extension but this is obviously wrong

Comment: If you have the staging script tag on the page, the staging library is already loaded.  Sounds like this is not the case for you, that you have the production library script tag on the page.  So, you can put it in stage mode by putting this into your js console: `localStorage.setItem('sdsat_stagingLibrary', true);_satellite.setDebug(true);location.reload();`  I personally just have it as a bookmark like so: `javascript:try{localStorage.setItem('sdsat_stagingLibrary', true);_satellite.setDebug(true);location.reload();}catch(e){}`  so i can just press a bookmark button

Comment: Also there is an [Adobe DTM Switch](https://marketing.adobe.com/resources/help/en_US/dtm/c_dtm_switch_plugins.html) browser plugin which basically does the same thing (though it doesn't reload the page when you flip switches, so you still have to do that for it to take effect)

Comment: I had both the scripts in there staging and production .. production was overriding staging. Commented out production and tested again and its working now. Thanks

Comment: Want to accept your answer so you get some points can you submit an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error message is output when

a) The direct call rule doesn't exist

b) The direct call rule isn't published and you are in published/live mode (which is effectively the same thing as (a), in principle)

If you are using the production tag, you can put it into staging/debug mode by entering the following into your js console:

```
localStorage.setItem('sdsat_stagingLibrary',true);_satellite.setDebug(true);location.reload();
```

You can make a browser bookmark out of it like so:

```
javascript:try{localStorage.setItem('sdsat_stagingLibrary',true);_satellite.setDebug(true);location.reload();}catch(e){}
```

Then you can just press a bookmark button to put it into staging/debug mode.

Also there is an [Adobe DTM Switch](https://marketing.adobe.com/resources/help/en_US/dtm/c_dtm_switch_plugins.html) browser plugin which basically does the same thing (though it doesn't reload the page when you flip switches, so you still have to do that for it to take effect).